# Environment variable set in batch file cannot be accessed in the C code compiled by the file

Tags: c, windows, batch-file

I'm setting a var using 
`set TEST_VAR=5` 
and then I'm compiling a C code. 
Error found during compilation is TEST_VAR is an undeclared variable.

Comment: Looks like a bug in line 42. When you go to the doctor, is all you say "ouch"?

Comment: When you set a variable using `Set` it is only available to that particular `cmd.exe` instance; _(local not global)_.

Comment: @Jens: My crystal ball indicate that the bug is in line 24. Perhaps you misread the line number? **`;)`**

Comment: Nah, Jens is obviously correct. It must be 42 - the universal answer to the ultimate question.

Comment: I have voted to delete this question, and am seeking two more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild-assed guess, because you don't even show a single line of C code: `getenv(TEST_VAR)` should be `getenv("TEST_VAR")`.

PS: To avoid downvotes for your next question (and possibly unhelpful answers like mine), please read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html explaining the art of asking smart questions.

Comment: Your "wild-assed guess" could explain the undeclared variable message.

Comment: The problem was with the CMake which was not able to access the environment variable TEST_ID.